# Trying to use Javascript ES6 modules.... now other functions are reported as being undefined when script is run

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I'm running into an odd problem, and I can't seem to find a solution.
I'm trying to pare down the number of individual scripts in my project, in part because they don't always play well together. But I want to use more than one script because there is a lot of code.

I thought a solution might be to incorporate some of the functionality into modules and import those functions I need for everything. But using the modules sets off a whole different set of problems. Specifically, some of the functionality that I've programmed into buttons now doesn't work, with a function not defined error in the console. Some, but not all, and I'll be damned if I see errors in the HTML or the Javascript. They all work as desired on the production site (https://theautotard.com/EP/), but not in the development build.

The only difference seems to be the modules. The imported functions work fine. I keep thinking this might be a strict mode issue, and I've researched that, but I can't see the problem. I am beyond frustrated at this point.

I am using the latest versions of VS Code and Chrome. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Modules are not declaring global variables, so you cannot access functions by name from button event handlers defined in the html. But that's a bad practice anyway, get rid of it and attach your event listeners from code.

Comment: Thanks... that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When you define functions or variables in either your web page or in `<script src>` scripts, they have `window` scope - that is, global scope.  But ES6 modules have their own scope. If you do this between `<script>` tags in your web page...

```
function someFunction() {
  //do something
}
```

...that function will be available to be called from anywhere else in the page - other scripts, event-handler attributes in your HTML, etc.  Defining the exact same function in a module may seem like you're doing the same thing, but you're not: functions (or variables) defined in a module are scoped to that module: *they can only be referenced from within that module.*

Unless you `export` them.  So, if you write a module like this...

```
function someFunction() {
  //do something
}

export default someFunction; // <- this allows someFunction() to be imported elsewhere
```

...then you can import this module into your web page and use the function there.  Without exporting (and importing somewhere else), your function can't be called from anywhere except within that module.

MDN is almost always a good place to get solid, up-to-date info on anything JavaScript-, CSS-, or DOM-related; this article on modules is worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Hope this helps - you're far from the only person to be tripped up by this, but this module-scoping works to everyone's advantage; it makes code conflicts (like one you mentioned, I believe) much less likely to happen since the global (`window`) scope doesn't get polluted nearly as much.